# Issues after migration from Spark 2.4.5 to Spark 3.2.0

Tags: apache-spark, stack-overflow

After migration from spark 2.4.5 version to spark 3.2.0, i see some issues in my app.

Mine is spark application that is being used ETL pipeline tasks.
There is one of the table which i used to import let's say X(with 229 columns).

With spark 2.4.5, there was no issue in importing it. But, with spark 3.2.0, i get Stackoverflow error.

Error stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.containsChild$lzycompute(TreeNode.scala:201)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.containsChild(TreeNode.scala:201)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChild$2(TreeNode.scala:612)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$4(TreeNode.scala:674)
scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:286)
scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:431)
scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:286)
scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:279)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:305)
```

Below are my observations,

1. At application startup, INFO message as "No custom resources configured for spark.driver."
2. A Default ResourceProfile created executor resources but that was not the case with spark 2.4.5
3. I already tried increasing the stack size using property "spark.executor.extrajavaoptions" but i can't keep on increasing it. i tried till -Xss1792m.

Is default resource profile is culprit here or anything else?

Comment: can you try to disable the `spark.sql.optimizer.maxIterations` or `spark.sql.optimizer.inSetConversionThreshold` options and see if anything change ? 
Also I won't be surprised if this is a bug in Spark, I would recommend upgrading to the latest version

Comment: Are these properties set by default? As i don't set it anywhere in spark config in app.

Comment: Are you able to post some code showing what the "import" looks like?  If you are using withColumn for each field rewrite it to use a single select(Column*) instead.

Comment: @Chris yes, i am using withColumn.  But i have a doubt, i was using the same method for spark version 2.4.5 and didn't face any issues. After upgrading to spark 3.2.1, it started popping up.